# Hailstone sequence method

Tags: java, sequence

This is the code I wrote for the hailstone sequence, but i cant get it to return the result im asked for, thes are the instructions to it. I feel like my main problem is with knowing where and how to save the numbers calculated.

```
For example, nextHailstone(1) should return "1 " and nextHailstone(5)
 * should return "5 16 8 4 2 1 ".
```

and here is my code, Im desperate, I get 8 4 2 1 1 instead of 5 16 8 4 2 1

```
public static String hailstones(int n) {
    String newNum = " ";
    if (n == 1)
    {
        return newNum = Integer.toString(n)+" ";
    }
    else 
    {   
    while   (n != 1 )
    {
    if (n% 2 == 0)
        {
            n = n/2;
            newNum = newNum + " " + n;

        }
    else  
        {
            n = n*3 + 1 ;
            newNum = newNum + " " + n;
        }
    }
}

return newNum = newNum + " "+ Integer.toString(n);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is needs some reordering and simplification. I suggest:

```
public static String hailstones(int n) {
    String result = "";
    while (n != 1) {
        result += Integer.toString(n) + " ";
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            n /= 2;
        } else {
            n = n * 3 + 1;
        }
    }
    result += "1";
    return result;
}
```